# How can I call a function when the mouse is no longer over a nav link?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have nav code like this in my HTML file:

```html
<div id="center_links">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" onMouseOver="javascript:setSideText(1)">about</a></li>
                <li><a href="blog" onMouseOver="javascript:setSideText(2)">blog</a></li>
```

...and so on.

My JavaScript looks like this:

```js
function setSideText(setting)
{
    if (setting == 0) // Home
    {
        document.getElementById('center_text').innerHTML = '<p><div class="dropcap">#</div>I am an information technology student interested in free and open source software.</p>';
    }
    else if (setting == 1) // About
    {
        document.getElementById('center_text').innerHTML = '<p><div class="dropcap">#</div>My name is David Gay, and this is my website. Welcome.</p>';
    }
    else if (setting == 2) // Blog
    {
        document.getElementById('center_text').innerHTML = '<p><div class="dropcap">#</div>My blog runs on the <a href="http://chyrp.net/">Chyrp</a> blog software.';
    }
```

When I `mouseover` a link, the side text on my page changes to describe the link. I want the text to change back to the default (`setSideText(0)`) when I'm not mousing over a nav link. I've been playing around with it for a bit now and I haven't been able to figure it out.

I tried adding this to the JavaScript file, but to no avail:

```js
document.getElementById('center_links').onMouseOut = setSideText(0);
```

I figured it wouldn't work, anyway.

I'm sure there's a simple solution that I'm not thinking of (I just picked up the language). Any guidance is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd make two primary suggestions, the first: don't use inline event-handlers (it's more maintainable to have your behaviour in one place) and the second is to use `onmouseout` on the parent `center_links` element.

To that end:

```
function setSideText(setting) {
    if (setting == 0) // Home
    {
        document.getElementById('center_text').innerHTML = '<p><div class="dropcap">#</div>I am an information technology student interested in free and open source software.</p>';
    }
    else if (setting == 1) // About
    {
        document.getElementById('center_text').innerHTML = '<p><div class="dropcap">#</div>My name is David Gay, and this is my website. Welcome.</p>';
    }
    else if (setting == 2) // Blog
    {
        document.getElementById('center_text').innerHTML = '<p><div class="dropcap">#</div>My blog runs on the <a href="http://chyrp.net/">Chyrp</a> blog software.';
    }
}

var linksElem = document.getElementById('center_links'),
    links = linksElem.getElementsByTagName('a');

for (var i = 0, len = links.length; i < len; i++) {
    links[i].dataIndex = i+1;
    links[i].onmouseover = function() {
        setSideText(this.dataIndex);
    };
}

linksElem.onmouseout = function(){
    setSideText(0);
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/3tGuk/).

---

**Edited** to amend the `setSideText()` function to respond to words rather than an index (because I think it's easier for adding subsequent links at a later date and doesn't rely on being able to add arbitrary attributes to the elements, though it *does* require that the element have an `id` attribute...):

```
function setSideText(setting) {
    if (setting == 'home' || setting == 0)
    {
        document.getElementById('center_text').innerHTML = '<p><div class="dropcap">#</div>I am an information technology student interested in free and open source software.</p>';
    }
    else if (setting == 'about')
    {
        document.getElementById('center_text').innerHTML = '<p><div class="dropcap">#</div>My name is David Gay, and this is my website. Welcome.</p>';
    }
    else if (setting == 'blog')
    {
        document.getElementById('center_text').innerHTML = '<p><div class="dropcap">#</div>My blog runs on the <a href="http://chyrp.net/">Chyrp</a> blog software.';
    }
}

var linksElem = document.getElementById('center_links'),
    links = linksElem.getElementsByTagName('a');

for (var i = 0, len = links.length; i < len; i++) {
    links[i].onmouseover = function() {
        setSideText(this.id);
    };
}

linksElem.onmouseout = function(){
    setSideText(0);
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/3tGuk/1/).

Comment: Alright, my code looks like yours but it's not working. The next does not change at all, on any mouseover. I'm still fiddling with it...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/WvTLH/ What a neat tool! For some reason, it's working there, but is not working properly locally in Firefox or on my web server (oddshocks.com).

Comment: Then it sounds like the problem is with code elsewhere (any typos in your HTML, maybe; or any variables being set elsewhere that conflict in some manner, if you're using the latter code example have your `a` elements got `id` attributes?).

Comment: My a elements have id attributes, as seen in the jsfiddle. I will spend some more time looking for typos and such. edit: Could it be something related to file linking? My links are typed properly, but maybe the jsfiddle worked because it knew where home.js was, but for some reason the browser can't find it normally?

Comment: Oh, and bear in mind that your copyright notice in your JS implies that the text-changing is your sole creation. I'd strongly suggest adding a link to this question, if only because of the [CC-BY-SA](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) license used by Stackoverflow. Oh, and do the elements you're binding events to exist in the DOM *before* you run the above code? Try putting the JavaScript into a `script` element into the bottom of the page, just before the `</body>` tag and see if that works.

Comment: Aha! Moving the `script` element as you suggested fixed the problem! Thanks for all the help! :)

Answer (score 1):

The only reason why that didn't work is because when setting these DOM events in Javascript, there is no capitalization; simply change `.onMouseOut` to `.onmouseout`.

I have no idea why they decided to be inconsistent between the HTML and Javascript names of these events. (Another reason why people hate on the DOM, I suppose.)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I made the change, but the side text still remains set to whatever the last mouseover command was, even if I move the mouse out of the nav div. Still playing with it.

Comment: Where in your JS is that ``.onmouseout`` called? It needs to be run *after* the DOM has been loaded, inside a ``document.onload`` event. Alternatively, @danblundell has another method to be sure the event handler is attached properly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to trigger the function onMouseOut the same way you trigger the function onMouseOver

Your link HTML needs to look like this:

```
<a href="blog" onMouseOver="javascript:setSideText(2)" onMouseOut="javascript:setSideText(0)">blog</a>
```

I would recommend looking into jQuery for stuff like this - it makes handling events and DOM manipulation much more straight forward!

There's a great free course here: http://tutsplus.com/course/30-days-to-learn-jquery/

Comment: This works, and if it's the easiest way to do it without jQuery, then I'll take it. ;) I was curious if there was a way to accomplish this without having to add onMouseOut to each link. And thanks for the link! I have been planning to learn jQuery for a few weeks now.

Comment: No problem - the tutorial's pretty clear and it'll take you through from basic events to full on plugin development. Highly recommended.

Comment: I would also say the response from Dave Thomas is much more full on - your code could be written in a much more reusable way but if you're new to js it's understandable!

Comment: Much more what-now..? Goodness, and to think I only ever learned JavaScript by accident... =)